# Position of an adverb

Tags: adverbs

Which sentence is correct, please? Or, do they differ in emphasis?

1. The remaining frequencies should **be preferentially** related to rotation or pulsations.
2. The remaining frequencies should **preferentially be** related to rotation or pulsations.

Comment: The first would require commas, the second would not.

Comment: In the first case, it's not clear if *preferentially* is modifying "related" or "be" (or the entire sentence). It depends if a relationship can be preferential.

Comment: *Idiomatically*, we're [much more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should+preferentially+be+used%2Cshould+be+preferentially+used&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) to place the (optional) adverbial element *between* the auxiliary *(**should be**)* and the "main" verb *(**related**)*. But that's just idiomatic preference - there's nothing wrong with putting the adverb in various other positions (including before or after the entire utterance). With this *specific* example, I can't see any scope for different meanings, or even subtly different *nuances*.

Comment: I think you mean: **preferably**, not preferentially.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are acceptable.

Both sentences are a bit awkward. They might be understood differently.

The first sentence will tend to be understood as there should be a preferential relationship, either between frequencies and rotation or frequencies and pulsations.

The second will tend to be understood as that it should be preferred there be a relationship, either between frequencies and rotation or frequencies and pulsations.

But either sentence will be a bit ambiguous in this regard. It is difficult to  confidently choose between these two alternatives.

You should rewrite these to make it more clear which you mean.

- It is preferred that frequencies be related to rotations or pulsations.
- It should be the case that a preferential relationship exists between frequencies and rotations or pulsations.

Comment: I don't buy the semantic distinction in this specific case, but I'm sure something could be illustrated using a *different* example of the same basic construction.

Comment: preferentially = as a (matter of) priority
I do not think that your suggested sentences have the same meaning.

Comment: @Anna-Kat They do not have the same meaning. That is the point.

Answer (score 0):

> The remaining frequencies should be preferentially related to rotation or pulsations.

I read:  "You should relate the frequencies that remain to rotation or pulsations, instead of relating them to other things, if you can."

> The remaining frequencies should preferentially be related to rotation or pulsations.

I read: "It is more desirable that the remaining frequencies are related to rotations or pulsations."

However, there is some ambiguity in meaning here, and the precise intention of "preferentially related" is not clear.  So if it is important, it should be clarified.

You might want to consider a general principle of technical writing here:  avoid the passive voice when possible.   By using active verbs, technical writing will become less ambiguous and more efficient at communicating detailed meaning.